# git config settings for large files

Tags: git, config

What are some recommended git config settings when working with very large binary files (> 500 MB)?

Reading [the documentation](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/git-config.html#_variables), it seems as if setting `pack.window` to 0, `pack.depth` to something very low like 2, and `pack.compression` to 0, git operations would be faster, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Are than any other options that I'm missing? I'm hoping to speed up even simple commands like `git log` because it seems to pause at every commit with a large file.

Comment: What options are you using to `git log`?  I wouldn't expect pauses unless you use an option that looks at the files, like `--stat`

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I had added --stat appended to an alias. I am still looking for optimal settings when working with only large files though.

Comment: Are the files essential? If not then you can create a suitable `.gitignore` file at the right location (unfortunately there is no size setting in `.gitignore` nor `.gitattributes`)

Comment: Yes, the files are essential to be tracked.

Comment: try the git@vger.kernel.org list to get the latest info (also on http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git). There have been recent patches for big file issues.

Comment: Maybe this extension for git can help: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't really any setting that can be considered "optimal."  Most people recommend the use of external asset management of some kind.  Personally, I would put the files on an ftp server, with YYYYMMDD## extensions, and then in my git repo have a small script that checks if I have the right version and downloads it if I don't, and check the *script* into git.  That way, you can still match versions of your source code with the right versions of your binary assets, but it isn't slowing down your git operations.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) is something I should look into.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Haven't heard of git-annex specifically, but it looks like exactly what you need.